# Using a URL query parameter to version cached responses

Tags: caching, service-worker

I am trying to cache specific urls and each url has md5 hash and If the urls updated with new md5 i want to remove the current cache and add the new one.
cached url:  http://www.mysite.lo/cards/index.php?md5=f51c2ef7795480ef2e0b1bd24c9e07

```
function shouldFetch(event) {
  if ( event.request.url.indexOf( '/cards/') ==  -1 ) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}



self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  if (shouldFetch(event)) {
    event.respondWith(    
          caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
              if (response !== undefined) {
                return response;
              } else {
                return fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
                  let responseClone = response.clone();

                  caches.open('v1').then(function (cache) {
                    cache.put(event.request, responseClone);
                  });
                  return response;
                }).catch(function (err) {
                  return caches.match(event.request);
                });
              }
        })
    );
}
});
```

I know we can use caches.delete() and so on, but I want to call it only if the md5 updated from the new request.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish roughly what you describe with the following, which makes use of the [`ignoreSearch` option](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/cache-query-options#ignoresearch) when calling `cache.matchAll()`:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const CACHE_NAME = '...';

  const url = new URL(event.request.url);
  if (url.searchParams.has('md5')) {
    event.respondWith((async () => {
      const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
      const cachedResponses = await cache.matchAll(url.href, {
        // https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/cache-query-options
        ignoreSearch: true,
      });

      for (const cachedResponse of cachedResponses) {
        // If we already have the incoming URL cached, return it.
        if (cachedResponse.url === url.href) {
          return cachedResponse;
        }
        // Otherwise, delete the out of date response.
        await cache.delete(cachedResponse.url);
      }

      // If we've gotten this far, then there wasn't a cache match,
      // and our old entries have been cleaned up.
      const response = await fetch(event.request);
      await cache.put(event.request, response.clone());

      return response;
    })());
  }

  // Logic for non-md5 use cases goes here.
});
```

(You could make things slightly more efficient by rearranging some of the cache-manipulation code to bring it out of the critical response path, but that's the basic idea.)